# Implement same page transition in UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, uiviewanimationtransition, page-curl, uideviceorientation

I have developing project in iOS 6.0 sdk which should work on iOS4.3+ devices, in my project i am using the page curl to navigate betwwen pages , but the page curl happening in LandscapeLeft is not as same as Pagecurl in Landscape Right. 
I want the same page curl that is happening in Landscape Left to be in Landscape right. 
Please take a look at the link for better understanding.
[Video Demo Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03Ck0cO4Mfk&feature=youtu.be)

The code i have used is shown below

```
    -(IBAction)nextBtnTapped {

    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation=[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    page2 *Obj=[[page2 alloc]init];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    if (deviceOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

    else if(deviceOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Obj animated:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(IBAction)prevBtnTapped {

    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation=[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];

    if (deviceOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

    else if(deviceOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Can any one please tell me what wrong have i done in this code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` with page curl is bugged. You won't get it to work correctly.

Comment: That is horrible to hear...Can you tell me the alternative for this.

Comment: Didn't find any (I am using Core Animation transitions directly). The only possibility is to use non-standard animations, e.g. https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl